# Different outputs of Scala toDebugString and Python toDebugString outputs

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using sample Word Count code from https://spark.apache.org/examples.html. 
There is a difference between outputs of function "toDebugString" applied on RDD generated after flatmap and map operations in Python(pySpark) and Scala Apache Spark.

Python(pySpark) code =>

```
text_file = sc.textFile("/Users/Aarti/Documents/Fall2017/Code/spark-2.2.0/Readme.md")
countsRDD = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
mapRDD = countsRDD.map(lambda word: (word, 1))
reducedRDD = mapRDD.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
print(mapRDD.toDebugString())
```

output:

```
(1) PythonRDD[3] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48 []
 |  /Users/Aarti/Documents/Fall2017/Code/spark-2.2.0/Readme.md 
MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0 []
 |  /Users/Aarti/Documents/Fall2017/Code/spark-2.2.0/Readme.md HadoopRDD[0] at 
textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0 []
```

Scala code =>

```
val text_file = sc.textFile("/Users/Aarti/Documents/Fall2017/Code/spark-2.2.0/Readme.md")
val countsRDD = text_file.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
val mapRDD = countsRDD.map(word => (word, 1))
val reducedRDD = mapRDD.reduceByKey(_ + _)
print(mapRDD.toDebugString)
```

output:

```
(1) MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at Test.scala:67 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[2] at flatMap at Test.scala:66 []
 |  /Users/Aarti/Documents/Fall2017/Code/spark-2.2.0/Readme.md 
MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at Test.scala:65 []
 |  /Users/Aarti/Documents/Fall2017/Code/spark-2.2.0/Readme.md HadoopRDD[0] at 
textFile at Test.scala:65 []
```

Scala output shows two different RDDs generated due to flatMap and Map operations clearly. On the other hand, python output does not show these operations and more importantly, it shows only one PythonRDD[3]. I think, PythonRDD[3] is generated due to map operation, but then is not PythonRDD[3] dependent on say the previous parent RDD, PythonRDD[2], generated due to flatMap operation as shown in Scala output.

Is there a way to track down these missing links? OR does pySpark behave differently than Scala spark internally?